# Why am I getting these Swift Compiler errors only when I Archive my app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios12, swift4.2

Using Xcode 10 GM and Swift 4.2, I am getting a number of compiling errors **only** when I Archive my app for upload to Apple. When I build and run in the Simulator *or* on device, the app runs just fine and Xcode shows no errors.

Anyone have any idea why this may be? There are a few areas that have errors, but here is one example:

```
public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    titles = Array<String>()
    visible = true
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    initialize()
}

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    titles = Array<String>()
    visible = true
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initialize()
}
```

[image]

Code is from the open source project from https://github.com/nicolasgomollon/STBTableViewIndex

---

Here's another example from my personal code that makes no sense:

```
var pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

[image]

`UIPageControl` does accept a frame when initializing, does it not? I'm confused.

Comment: Are there any differences between your debug and release build configurations?

Comment: I looked and I couldn't find anything that stood out. I tried to change some of the standard build settings (such as speed and size optimizations, etc) to match the Debug versions, and I still get the errors. When I reverse my Swift 4.2 syntax back to Swift 4.0 and run the project in Xcode 9, I can Archive it just fine.

Comment: I also tried both the old and new build system and had the same results with each.

Comment: I suspect that something is hung to Swift 4 in your project, but I don't really know how to figure it out. You should open the Report navigator (⌘9, or last tab in the left sidebar), select an unsuccessful build and expand the command line for one file that failed, then do the same thing for a successful build, and compare the two. The easiest way to do that, IMO, is to replace `" -"` in the command line with `"\n-"` and using some diff tool. That will hopefully help you isolate possible causes.

Comment: I have the same issue. It compiled fine one time after deleting `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache`, but now it's back at it. The code itself is fine, it works great in isolation in a playground. It has to be a compiler issue.

Comment: @andreamazz - Please file a bug with Apple. That is what I have done. They need to get this fixed ASAP. Attach your project so they can repro.